# How does WordPress create its database during installation?

Tags: database, scripts

I am new to WordPress  and I'm trying to understand it. I searched for a .sql file in WordPress  script but couldn't find any. Wm kinda confused and want to know where the database entries and commands that create the database during WordPress  installation is located in the WordPress  script.

Comment: Take a look at `wp-admin/includes/schema.php` https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/includes/schema.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

schema.php file holds create the database table on installation

You will get that file in wp-admin/includes/schema.php

Hope you have get your answer.

Answer (score -2):

There isn't a .sql file. The settings are in a .php file.

It is usually found at the top of wp-config.php in the root directory of the WordPress installation, and looks like this:

```
 /**
 * The base configurations of the WordPress.
 *
 * This file has the following configurations: MySQL settings, Table Prefix,
 * Secret Keys, and ABSPATH. You can find more information by visiting
 * {@link http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php Editing wp-config.php}
 * Codex page. You can get the MySQL settings from your web host.
 *
 * This file is used by the wp-config.php creation script during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can just copy this file
 * to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'dbname');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'username');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '123password');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is not straightforward enough but what I really meant was: which file holds the sql commands that creates the database tables on installation?